# joomla how to call back end function in form action at module

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-component, joomla-module

this is my file structure in my modules: /module/com_somthing

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="e_brochure" name="e_brochure"    method="post" action=">
</form>
```

this is my file structure in my controller.php: admin/component/com_somthing

```
function addreqinfo()
{
}
```

I want to call addreqinfo when form submit / on action

Answer (score 1):

Functions in the controller are called by tasks.
Your action link in the form will be *something like* this:

```
JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_somthing&task=addreqinfo")
```

JRoute will create an SEO friendly version of the URL depending how your router is set up in the component.

Further info here:
http://docs.joomla.org/Absolute_Basics_of_How_a_Component_Functions

(NB also - a module and a component are different things - worth learning the difference if you are using Joomla)

Comment: JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_somthing&task=addreqinfo") this i already did...But i want to call task from admin/component/com_somthing/view/controller.php

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Richard's correct answer, depending on need you can call methods on a particulars views controller as well.  So if you had a widgets view and wanted to use AJAX to call the update() method in the widgets controller you could using below url:

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_something&task=widgets.update');
```

You can also add any needed additional parameters to the url; and as a best practice be sure to attach a token to the form or url parameters for security purposes.